# AngularJs Wizard Validation Inputfield can't find scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, wizard, ngboilerplate

i'm new in AngularJs and have a problem with my code.

At the moment my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="wizardContainer">
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()">
    <wz-step title="1">
        <h1>Question 1</h1>
        <p>How old are you?</p>
        <form name="age_form" novalidate ng-submit="signupForm()">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="age" ng-model="user.age"
                       ng-minlength=1 required>

                <div class="error-container"
                     ng-show="age_form.age.$invalid && age_form.submitted">
                    <small class="error"
                           ng-show="age_form.age.$error.required">
                        Please fill in the field
                    </small>
                    <small class="error"
                           ng-show="age_form.age.$error.minlength">
                        Please fill in mininum 1 number
                    </small>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default full-width">go on</span></button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step title="2">
        <h1>Question 2</h1>
        <p>How are you?</p>
    </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

and my Controller looks like:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate.about', [
    'ui.router',
    'placeholders',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'mgo-angular-wizard'
])

.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'AboutCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'about/about.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data: { pageTitle: 'What is It?' }
    });
})

.controller('AboutCtrl', function AboutCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.submitted = false;

    $scope.signupForm = function() {
      if ($scope.age_form.$valid) {
          window.location="#/about";
      } else {
        $scope.age_form.submitted = true;
      }
    };
});
```

If i click on the submit button in the first step of the wizard i get an error in the console with the message : $scope.age_form is undefined

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The angular wizard project currently has scoping problems.  I was able to solve it at the post, below.

Trying to get form validations to work with an Angular Wizard
[I'm trying to get form validations to work with an Angular Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153230/im-trying-to-get-form-validations-to-work-with-an-angular-wizard/26206573#26206573)

However, this is a temporary fix.  The project definitely needs to be reworked.

It's all tied to this issue on github.

Step validation?!
https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard/issues/41