# I'm trying to get form validations to work with an Angular Wizard

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am using an angular wizard for my app's registration process.

Angular Wizard - 
https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

However, no matter what I try, each step of the wizard is not allowing for form validation (which basically comes out of the box with angular and the use of forms with the FormController and the $error object.

I have posted on the project's issues page regarding form validation, but I have not heard from the owner of the project or from any other users with examples of working code, so I'm hoping some more advanced users here can help.

Oh and to help isolate the problem, I have only included the html for the first step in my jsfiddles.

Validation Issue - https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard/issues/41

The validation issue page links to my jsfiddles and other efforts.

Is this a scoping problem???? If so, how do I get around it? Currently when I click the Next button, it just progresses through the wizard, and when I try to send the $error object to the console, all I get is "undefined".

Angular docs (form properties and reference to $error)  - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a scoping problem. I was able to get things to work by reaching into the scope of a child element (in the controller) and by defining the variables in the view (html) as being part of the $parent element. This means that all of the variables are set in HTML as

```
ng-model="$parent.variableName";
```

Changing this variable's value from the controller requires a call as follows:

```
$scope.$$childTail.variableName = 'something that you want to change the value to';
```

But reaching into $$childTail is a no-no. This whole project needs to be reworked to fix the scoping problem if you ask me. And there needs to be documentation on how to access validation variables if the revised project uses anything outside of typical angular data binding.

My solution code is attached in gists, below.

Controller Setup
https://gist.github.com/Shawful/a4f8ff5097eabc5306f4

HTML Setup
https://gist.github.com/Shawful/f8dc97d6fd88bbb111f9

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is the lack of dotted notation on your ng-models.  In general you want ng-model="container.piece".  There are numerous articles on the problem of writing to a child scope if your models do not contain a dot in them.  Have a look at [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: This is correct normally, but as @Shawesome mentioned this is a major issue with this library.